# GNU Parallel runs in script interactively but not in same script via crontab

Tags: parallel-processing, cron, gnu-parallel

I'm using GNU Parallel version 20141122 to curl 100 IP addresses in parallel within a larger script.

When I execute the script interactively, Parallel produces the expected results in a log file.

When I run the same script via a crontab job, no entries are added to the log file although the remainder of the script produces expected results for all of the non-Parallel-related tasks.

The line in the script that executes Parallel is

```
parallel -j30 < contactdevices.input
```

The file contactdevices.input contains 100 lines like this:

```
./contactdevice.sh  155.156.157.158
```

contactdevice.sh curls the IP address and appends a one line result to a log file.

My Amazon AMI environment supports more than 40 such simultaneous jobs.

Why does Parallel work within my script when run interactively but appears not to run at all when the identical script is executed via crontab?

Thanks for your help. I'm pretty much a linux and bash neophyte.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the problem with `cron` is that you have a limited $PATH. Try setting that:

PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/the/dir/containing/contactdevice

and then remove the ./

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Ole.I have other scripts that are called via the ./ mechanism from my main script that work with cron.  I can try PATH, but because of the success of the other called scripts I suspect the problem is something else.  Spawned process limit?  Child process limit?

Comment: Your system is severely brainf*cked if you are limited to fewer than 30 processes. And IF that is the case, the -j1 ought to work.

Answer (score 0):

The `parallel` utility was installed in the the user's bin folder rather than `/usr/bin`. Installing the utility in `/usr/bin` solved the problem.  Alternatively, we could have solved the problem by specifying the location of `parallel` when invoking it.

Comment: So it was a $PATH thing. Adding the user's bin to $PATH would probably also have worked.